# Styleci fixes phpdoc comments at file level

Tags: laravel, styleci

I specify phpdoc for $factory variable in [ModelFactory](https://github.com/melihovv/laravel-starter-kit/blob/21722f655e372d007ccd0d8881a89e1cb9480c57/database/factories/ModelFactory.php#L17) for completion in PhpStorm.

```
/**
 * @var Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory
 */
$factory->define(App\Models\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
```

However, when I push commit to github, styleci send me such [pull request](https://styleci.io/analyses/8bObv5)

```
-/**
+/*
  * @var Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory
  */
 $factory->define(App\Models\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
```

But PhpStorm doesn't recognize such comments and there is no completion. Is it possible to tell styleci not to fix phpdoc comments at file level?

My .styleci looks like this

```
preset: recommended
risky: true
linting: true
disabled:
  - align_double_arrow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have experience with StyleCI, and this is not tested, but a quick glance at the documentation shows this fixer:

> **phpdoc_to_comment**
>
> Docblocks should only be used on structural elements.

To me, it sounds like this fixer is responsible for changing your PHPDoc comment to a plain comment, since it is not describing a structural element. I would try adding this fixer to your `disabled` list.